# Android Print SDK for Receipt Printers

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth, usb

I need an android SDK for my app which has to support all Bluetooth, USB and IP connections for any third party printer.

I've tried using EPSON SDK, STAR SDK, ZEBRA SDK and Brother SDK. Those SDKS are not supporting third party printers.

Except EPSON SDK is supporting IP connection. I've tried to tweak the code of EPSON SDK, but the USB printing is not working and bluetooth printing is working very slow.

Can you suggest any SDK which support all three connections for third party printers?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this https://www.hprt.com/Download/TP806.html 
include android SDK, apk, and source code.
May be generally works in bluetooth and ip connection.

Be careful for print image, it can be different esc pos command for each printer.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: that link is now dead

Comment: @MonOve here is the printer http://www.hprt.com/Product/POS-Printers/TP806.html and here is the sdk downlodad page: http://www.hprt.com/Downloads.html Notice that the website is not working anymore with https (expired certificate?)